# Speedup webrequest code

Tags: c#, performance

I am having some performance problems with the code below, the post request takes approximately 1.5 seconds, I was wondering if there are some more methods to use to speed up this process? I tried using the `Proxy = null;` method. Maybe it's because of parsing the data to an dynamic object?

```
public void loginWithUsernamePassword(string username, string password)
{
    Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    stopwatch.Start();

    WebClient n = new WebClient();
    object request = new { username = username, password = password };

    try
    {
        string data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request); 
        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://192.168.201.10/api/v1/auth/login");

        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("X-Api-Key", cocusAPI.Apikey);
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
        httpWebRequest.Proxy = null;

        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            streamWriter.Write(data);
            streamWriter.Flush();
            streamWriter.Close();
        }

        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            dynamic item = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(result);
            if (item.data.success == true)
            {
                Consolelog("API loginWithUsername successfull");
                cocusAPI.Accesstoken = httpResponse.GetResponseHeader("X-Access-Token");
            }
            else
            {
                Consolelog("login failed"); 
            }
        }

        stopwatch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(stopwatch.Elapsed);
    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {
        var resp = new StreamReader(ex.Response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
        Consolelog(resp);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to do a POST by other means than your code? For example, Postman Chrome extension. This will tell you which side is slow - server or client.

Comment: If you really want to know where the slowness is you could add Console.WriteLine(stopwatch.Elapsed) in various spots to figure it out or use the performance tools in Visual Studio. Getting a response could potentially take a second.

Comment: If you know the type of the deserialized object, there's no need to use `dynamic`. Just use `DeserializeObject<MyType>(result)`. When you use `dynamic` you're effectively invoking (a subset of) the compiler, and if you're worried about performance, that doesn't sound like a good thing.

Comment: @KSib I was aware of that, doing some more research tells me that if (item.data.success == true) takes around half a second, DeserializeObject  only 30ms

Comment: @ErwinVorenhout: yes, but DeserializeObject isn't "interpreting" (or compiling) the object in any way. It's when you access a property that the "dynamic" nature of the object requires the C# `dynamic` mechanism to kick in to figure out what methods / properties the object has. So, again, try using `DeserializeObject<MyType>` if you can.